# How can I have Google Sheets automatically parse and calculate text that follows a certain pattern?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I have the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEMjWVEwyuqbn_imW1UZ-AF2NlE__IbRZdHQifKJjko/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to calculate "Total Work" by deriving it from my own notation.  When I do 6 sets of 10 reps of bench press at 200lbs, I want to write and see `6x10x200`, but then, in addition, see a "total work" computation that recognizes the pattern `NUMxNUMxNUM`, or `NUMxNUMxNUM, NUMxNUMxNUM`

If this problem would become much easier to solve with some adjustments to my notation, for example, `NUM*NUM*NUM`, this would work perfectly fine.

Comment: can you add example of desired output?

Comment: @user0 sure!  good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
 SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C3, "((.*))", ""), ",")&"x1")), "x"), 
 "select Col1*Col2*Col3 label Col1*Col2*Col3''", 0))))
```

[image: 0]